# Restore a Minimized Windows Mobile Application Form from c++

Tags: c#, visual-c++, windows-mobile

I have a Compact .Net 2.0 Application (Targeting Windows Mobile 2003 and Above) that has a button to Minimize the Form. I use P/Invoke to Minimize the form/application

```
//[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
ShowWindow(this.Handle /* Handle for the Form */, SW_MINIMIZED /*6*/)
```

I have another simple program Splash.exe written in C++ that starts the compact.net application. The purpose of the Splash program is to check if the .Net Application is running and either Restore the .Net Form if running or Start the .Net application if not.

I use the following procedure to check if the .Net application is running:

```
HWND GetProcessIfAlive(TCHAR szExeName[MAX_PATH]) /* Exe name of the .Net App */
{ 
        HANDLE         hSnapShot = NULL; 
        PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry = {0};
        // Get the snapshot of the system
        hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
        pEntry.dwSize = sizeof(pEntry);

        //Get first process
        Process32First(hSnapShot, &pEntry);

        //Iterate thru all processes
        while(TRUE)
        {
            TCHAR *strTempExe = pEntry.szExeFile;
            if(_tcscmp(strTempExe, szExeName) == 0)
            {
                DWORD ProcesID = pEntry.th32ProcessID;
                return (HWND)OpenProcess (PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, ProcesID);
                //return (HWND)ProcesID;
            }

            if(!Process32Next (hSnapShot, &pEntry)/* == FALSE*/)
            {
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        return NULL;
}
```

After returning from this procedure, I try to restore the Form using

```
HWND hExistingHandle = GetProcessIfAlive(TEXT("CompactDotNetApp.exe"));
if(hExistingHandle != NULL)
{
    if(ShowWindow(hExistingHandle, SW_RESTORE) == FALSE)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
    }
}
```

I am getting error 1400 [ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

How can I fix the code the get the proper window Handle for the running Compact .Net Application?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use ShowWindow on a process handle, not a Window handle, which is invalid.  You would need the handle to your main app window, which you could get with FindWindow calls, but it's a kludge.

A better approach here is a 2-part solution.

First use a named mutex.  Create the mutex when the managed app starts and release it when you exit.  The C app can then just check to see if the mutex exists to determine if the app is running or not - no toolhelp work needed.

The second part of the solution is to have your managed app launch a thread (or a timer) to periodically check for a named system event.  If it finds that the event is set, it then maximizes the main form and brings it fore.

Back in the C app, if the mutex is found to exist (the app is running) then you simply set the event and exit.  That will trigger the thread in the manged app to bring itself to the fore.